# Find all possible sequences of 3 repeating numbers in 2d array

Tags: java, c#, loops, multidimensional-array

Let's say that I have this following 2d array:

```
int[][] array = {{1,4,4,6,6,3},
                {4,8,6,5,7,3},
                {6,6,9,3,3,9}};
```

I need to find all the sequences of 3 or more repeating numbers,
for example, in this array, the output should be 3, because we have 3 times 4,
five times 6 and 3 times 3, the sequences must be diagonal or horizontal.
I how to solve this.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: java and c#? why tagging both? and what have you tryed already?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with your progress so far. Be sure to include a set of various inputs and the outputs you expect for each of those inputs.

Comment: Linq SelectMany, GroupBy and Count would be one option in c#.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this:

```
int[][] arrays = new int[][] {
    new []{1,4,4,6,6,3},
    new []{4,8,6,5,7,3},
    new []{6,6,9,3,3,9}
};

var list = new List<int>();

foreach (var array in arrays)
    list.AddRange(array);

var result = list.GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .Where(x => x.Count > 2);
```

Because you want to use all arrays together, you can put all of them in one list. With this list you can count the numbers with linq. The variable result contains all elemnts, which are three or more times in the list.